# ASP .Net. Как получить данные из WSDL файла?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, wsdl

У меня есть ссылка на wsdl файл. Как мне получить данные по заданному url? Я делаю так:

```
public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    return webRequest;
}

HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest("https://71.29.167.165/client/OneTouch/test/NationalAgentAPI?wsdl");
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{

}
```

Но что дальше, не понятно.

Вид wsdl:

```
<WL5G3N0:definitions xmlns:WL5G3N0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://partnerapi.windstream.com" xmlns:WL5G3N2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://partnerapi.windstream.com">
<WL5G3N0:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://partnerapi.windstream.com" xmlns:intf="http://partnerapi.windstream.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://partnerapi.windstream.com">
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
<xsd:complexType name="requesterInfo">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="transactionId" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="applicationName" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="applicationId" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ServiceabilityName">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="firstName" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="middleInitial" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="lastName" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Какие именно данные вам нужны?

Comment: @PavelMayorov - у меня есть локальный этот файл, я его переделал в классы с свойствами с помощью встроенной функции. Но мне теперь нужно это сделать программно и по url

Comment: Зачем? Что вы предполагаете дальше делать с неизвестными вам на этапе компиляции классами?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно было просто подключить в References и всё доступно.

References ПКМ -> Add Service Referenc... 
Потом вставить ссылку в Address и нажать Go

После этого доступны классы и свойства

Comment: Вы же написали в комментариях, что уже сделали это? В чем проблема-то была, в таком случае?

Comment: @PavelMayorov до этого у меня был wsdl файл, хранящийся локально, а мне нужно было вытащить его по url